OneNote Change Notebook File location
I am trying to change the storage path of a OneNote NoteBook. The code does not return an error, but the new path is not applied in OneNote.
What action do I need to perform to change the path.
$OneNoteNoteBookName = 'TT11'
$OneNote = New-Object -ComObject OneNote.Application
[xml]$Hierarchy = ""
$OneNote.GetHierarchy("", [Microsoft.Office.InterOp.OneNote.HierarchyScope]::hsPages, [ref]$Hierarchy,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.XMLSchema]::xs2013)

$Index = [array]::IndexOf($Hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook.Name, $OneNoteNoteBookName)

$NewNotBookFolderPath = $(Join-Path $OneDriveOneNoteFolderPath -ChildPath $Hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook[$Index].Name) 
IF($(Test-Path $NewNotBookFolderPath) -eq $false)
{
    $NewNoteBookFolderObj = mkdir $NewNotBookFolderPath
}else{
    $NewNoteBookFolderObj = Get-Item $NewNotBookFolderPath
}
$OldNoteBookRootPath = $Hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook[$Index].Attributes['path'].Value

# Copy NoteBook Content
Copy-Item -Path $($Hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook[$Index].path) -Destination $($NewNoteBookFolderObj.FullName) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force

# Update Main Notebook Path
$Hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook[$Index].Attributes['path'].Value = $Hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook[$Index].path -replace [regex]::Escape($Hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook[$Index].path), $NewNoteBookFolderObj.FullName

# Update Child Notebook Path
Foreach($Page in $Hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook[$Index].ChildNodes) 
{
    $Page.Attributes['path'].Value = $Page.path -replace [regex]::Escape($OldNoteBookRootPath), $NewNoteBookFolderObj.FullName
}

# Update Hierarchy
$OneNote.UpdateHierarchy($Hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook[$Index].OuterXML)

